# ValueError: Please supply either code or authorization_response parameters

Tags: python, oauth-2.0

I am doing every bit what was asked in this document of [requests-oauthlib](http://requests-oauthlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/facebook.html).

After this line I am getting an url which I opened on browser and I got redirected.

`Value of redirected_url :http://localhost:5000/?code=AQBuWYEa4ohlALbiO_lqhwjvDE8PJnzRana6gDrVwY6YtK0oo1T4tuqO_41sTQKvcWbirMAfrgALF8ijEnxTSYUwlOSqi8Si5ROtvzhOsuvMXJBm3n89UBK28Z5ZvZHaJJHS0dySldcqXmL8K4YScx5AlGL0EgCTvO1hqB6O1t368WB6m-C7gowrzNTH9qdiI_2c4mzu4j9XG0ENIh2bE_CU5zTVXPt9kb4W7Q-MM8loEwUc17XdjV6-1LxQ6QrTxv8EwRxsX6TSoVoWCFuvYfdtaEnmxFiC5Bjg7qzBLc02k_ZYxY_2qR_artYIcjSe5H0&state=Vs3nqCxJNQ99scgiZdsMoHBTB8F6XV#_=_`

`redirect_response = raw_input('Paste the full redirect URL here:')`

Now what should I paste here I treied pasting only code or full url but its not happening.

Error: `ValueError: Please supply either code or authorization_response parameters.`